# LinkButtons in IE10 not performing posting back

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to add a simple `LinkButton` to an ASP.NET 4 page but it's not calling the `postback` in IE10. The code looks like as follows.

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
    OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

As you can see, it's just a plain page. However, I cannot get the `LinkButton` to call the method since upgrading to Win8 and IE10. This works fine with Firefox.

Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: 1) Check for script errors in IE 10, 2) try running as IE 8 or 9 (F12 developer tools).

Comment: I can't see any script errors in the IE10 status bar and via the developer tools and changing the browser to IE7/8/9 doesn't effect the link button postback. I've also tried changing the user agent string down to IE8/9 to see if that helped.

Answer (score 5):

This is a server patching/updating problem. ASP.NET has not emitted the correct JavaScript for your browser to run. It's not aware of IE versions newer than IE9.

See Scott Hanselman's post on this:

[ASP.NET fails to detect IE10 causing _doPostBack is undefined JavaScript error or maintain FF5 scrollbar position](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Scott notes in this 2011 post that the fix should be distributed via Windows Update. Ensure your server is up to date with .NET Framework service updates from Windows Update. If not, [you can download the patch](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2600088) or [read more details on the Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088).

The fix will update those `.browser` files allowing ASP.NET to emit the correct markup and JavaScript.

> %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework(64?)\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\Browsers\ie.browser

This will contains items like this:

```
  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0) -->
  <browser id="IE10Plus" parentID="IE6Plus">
    <identification>
      <capability name="majorversion" match="\d{2,}" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
```

Comment: A small addition that Scott Hanselman mentions is that if for some reason you don't have access to system files, you can always add the updated definitions to the website itself by using the WEB_BROWSER asp folder. This can be found in section SITE-ONLY FIXES

Comment: @mrd3650 you are correct, but it is the "App_Browsers" folder, not "web_browser"

Comment: @Mark Cooper Cheers for noting

Answer (score 5):

Explanation about the error:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

If you want the direct download (Framework 4.0) to the Hotfix is:

http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%204.0%20-%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%202003,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Win7,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20(MSI)/nosp/DevDiv953277/30319.504/free/436907_intl_x64_zip.exe

Comment: Do not give the direct link to the exe, link to the page explaining the hotfix

Comment: The explanation is exactly the topic of this issue

Comment: But the exe's can be withdrawn or updated, while the KB links should stick around. Also, he may not want that particular version of the file.

Comment: Zhaph  I've added an explanation, but I think it helped a some people this is the point we need to care about.

Answer (score 3):

You have patch who patch introduces the updated definitions in the browser definition files for Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. The browser definition files are stored in the following folders, depending on the installed version of Microsoft Framework le.NET:

For 32-bit versions of the Framework 4.0.NET

% WinDir% \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ CONFIG \ Browsers

For 64-bit versions of the Framework 4.0.NET

% WinDir% \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ CONFIG \ Browsers

Download Patch here : http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2600088&kbln=fr

Link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. It looks like the image validation service is down so I can't download the hot fix at the moment also it looks like its only up to Win7. I'm running Win8 RTM

Comment: When I try and run that hotfix I get: KB2600088 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer. So I guess it's not compatible with Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

It was due to the security settings in IE10. For some reason my local intranet settings were stricter than public websites. So I couldn't click on hyperlinks, but I could click on buttons which submitted forms.

Answer (score 2):

You should install .Net Framework 4.5, it worked for me.

Comment: such a huge bug in Dot Net/IE that both of its products are not compatible with each other? what if my host supports only 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a hotfix for this. Scott Hanselman explains this on his blog.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx