# LinkButton occasionally not firing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a well-established website where you can take tests ([www.skills-assessment.net](http://www.skills-assessment.net), but I'm only including that in case it helps anyone answer this).  Every day a couple of hundred people successfully complete tests, but the odd one gets stuck on the first question.  It seems that clicking on a link button to advance to the next question doesn't do anything.

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the operating system or browser used.  The site runs in .NET framework 4.0, and uses VB (for what that's worth).  It makes copious use of user controls.

Here's one of the user controls which I don't think has firing link buttons:

```
 <%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ucQuestionAnswer.ascx.vb" Inherits="ucQuestionAnswer" %>

<!-- hidden viewstate labels -->
<asp:Label ID="lblQuestionId" runat="server" Visible="false" />

<div class="answerItemLetter">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbAnswerLetter" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="answerItemText"><asp:Label ID="lblAnswerText" Runat="server" /></div>

<asp:Label ID="lblAnswerChar" runat="server" Text="Answer as character" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

Here's the code-behind for this link button:

```
 Protected Sub lkbAnswerLetter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lkbAnswerLetter.Click

    'if user chose an answer, process it
    RaiseEvent AnswerClicked(Convert.ToChar(Me.lkbAnswerLetter.CommandArgument))

End Sub
```

I'm not sure this'll be much help to anyone, as it may not be where the problem is occurring anyway.

I've scoured the web for answers, but come up with nothing (lots of people have link buttons not firing, but no one seems to have an intermittent problem).

Comment: Isn't it the common issue with lack of postback scripts on IE10?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this bug in your browser?

Comment: Have you had user reporting this to you ? Could it be an unrelated Javascript problem causing the javascript execution to stop ? Is there any common point to the users having the problem ? I thik the answer is anyway to be found client-side, as it is "random"

Comment: Could you show us an exact page and button on your site (www.skills-assessment.net), which cause a problem?

Comment: At least some of the people reporting the problem have JavaScript enabled.  If you start any test, it comes up with the first question.  You can't then continue from this first question, no matter what answer you choose!

I realise by its nature this is going to be hard to solve - just thought someone might have seen it and suggest a reason.

Comment: No, I can't reproduce the bug, and no it isn't to do with postback scripts on IE10, I don't think, as it runs fine in IE10 on my computer.  Having said which, maybe I should take the advice at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449934/linkbuttons-in-ie10-not-performing-posting-back and install .NET 4.5?